# Update one-to-many/many-to-one associated object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This feels like a really stupid question but I can't seem to find an example anywhere. Maybe I google using the wrong keywords.

Either way what I am trying to do is to update a One-To-Many mapping.

The Category class:

```
public class Category {
    ...
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity = Color.class, mappedBy="category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Color> colors;
}
```

Tye Color class:

```
public class Color {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "COLOR_ID")
    private Long color_id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID", nullable=false)
    private Category category;
    ...
}
```

I want to update a Color so that it now belongs to Category2 instead of Category1. The issue is that if I delete the Color from Category1 and update it  and then add the Color to Category2 and update Category2, the color will then have a new ID. I want the ID to be retained.

I have tried to add the Color to Category2 and just change the category of the Color to Category2 and then persisting Category2. Then the state of the data in the database is correct but the cached Category1 object in Hibernate isn't updated.

I use a JPA EntityManager for persisting objects.

Edit:

As requested, here is a breakdown of the code I run to move the Color to another category.

```
color = category1.getColors().remove(color);
color.setCategory(category2);
category2.getColors().add(color);

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.merge(category1);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
entityManager.merge(category2);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

String queryString = getQueryString();
List<Category> categories = null;
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
categories = query.getResultList();
```

The Color is now in the new category but with a new ID.

Comment: If you post the code snippet showing what you do instead of describing it in words, someone might see where the problem lies.

Comment: What happens if you remove `orphanRemoval=true` from the `@OneToMany`?